# Sending data from Mysql with Json using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to send data from a Mysql database using Json. As long as it is only 1 post in the database it works, but when its more rows its nor working anymore.

Here is the PHP code:
    // array for JSON response
    $response = array();

```
$data = new CDatabaseInfo();
$result = $data ->selectAll();
$data->closeDatabase();

// check for empty result
if (isset($result)) {

    $response["products"] = array();
    foreach($result as $value) {
        $product = null;
        $product = array();
        $product["pid"] = $value["pid"];
        $product["name"] = $value["name"];
        $product["price"] = $value["price"];
        $product["description"] = $value["description"];
        $product["created_at"] = $value["created_at"];
        $product["updated_at"] = $value["updated_at"];
        array_push($response["products"], $product);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;
    echo json_encode($response, TRUE);
    echo "var dump <br>";
    var_dump($response);
}
```

Here comes the result of var_dump:

```
array(2) { ["products"]=> array(2) {[0]=> array(6) { ["pid"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(6) "Festis" ["price"]=> string(5) "20.00" ["description"]=> string(9) "God dryck" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2015-07-09 20:31:30" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" } [1]=> array(6) { ["pid"]=> string(1) "4" ["name"]=> string(4) "Cola" ["price"]=> string(5) "12.00" ["description"]=> string(11) "En fin läsk" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2015-07-20 20:29:03" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" } } ["success"]=> int(1) }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as `json_encode($response, TRUE);`

Be sure you get the right data from the database. Beside the little error, your code should run correctly.

Comment: I took away TRUE but still its not working for arrays that is bigger than 1 row. When its only 1 row, its works perfectly

Comment: I just ran your code with some random data in $result and it works fine.

Comment: I took away $response["products"] = array(); and typed: $response = array(); instead, then I just typed: $response[] = $value; in the foreach iteration.